# "Unresolved filter" warning in WebStorm, working with Vue

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

No matter what filter I use in my Vue templates, it underlines them in green with a message,  "Unresolved filter"

How do I resolve this? Or should I file an issue with WebStorm? My filters are defined in an external module.

[image]

Comment: Are those filters declared in the same template? If this filter is defined in another place not tracked in the current source code, it will keep underlined.

Comment: any warning or error from Vue core? or only Webstorm popped up this error?

Comment: @F.Igor Yep, I edited my post to clarify that. My filters are defined outside the component file. Is there some way to just disable the "Unresolved filter" message without disabling it for other types of unresolved symbols?

Comment: Looks similar to [WEB-42191](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42191). Please follow this issue for updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Known issue:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42191

Hopefully it'll be addressed at some point in the future.

Comment: still unresolved...

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all or specific unresolved items following the instruction here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html?keymap=secondary_eclipse#disable-inspections

For a specific case:

> Disable an inspection in the editor﻿
>
> Place the caret at the highlighted line and press ⌥⏎
> (or click the Intention action icon to use the intention action).
>
> Click the arrow next to the inspection you want to disable, and select
> Disable inspection.